# how to use ExcelColumn in LinqToExcel c#?

Tags: c#, linq, xlsx, linq-to-excel

I had added Attributes to model I want my xls file to be bind. Like:

```
[ExcelColumn("Id")]
public string Id{ get; set; }
```

But after all I need to specify mapping anyway, because there is no AddMapping overload without any arguments:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(xlsxFilePath);
excel.AddMapping<XlsxFile>(x => x.Id, "Id");
```

Is there a way to map it just by using attributes, without x => x.Id, "Id" part?
I have found this documentation, but I can't find anything https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel

Comment: I found the codeproject page gives better documentation and examples. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659643/Csharp-Query-Excel-and-CSV-Files-Using-LinqToExcel

Comment: There are still no information about ExcelColumn attribute

Comment: and what happens if you don't call AddMapping?

Comment: I have to specify the mapping class (model) at some point. AddMapping method creates list of mapped objects, so It seems to be important.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was the solution :)

```
public IEnumerable<XlsxFile> import(string xlsxFilePath, string SheetName)
{
    using (var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(xlsxFilePath))
    {
        return from x in excel.Worksheet<XlsxFile>(SheetName) where x != null select x;
    }
}
```